# Check or catch warning failed to post notification on channel

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, android-notifications

I know why this warning appears in my case I didn't create channel but it is not the question
, what I want to know is how to catch it or check if channel exist it in the code in order to handle it before publishing the notification.

> "Developper warning for package "com.app" failed to post notification
> on channel "channel1" see log for more details"
> thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `NotificationManager.GetNotificationChannel` and it will return an instance of the `NotificationChannel` if it exists or a `null` if it does not.

Quick Example:

```
using (var notificationManager = NotificationManager.FromContext(ApplicationContext))
{
    var channelName = "SomeChannelName";
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.O)
    {
        NotificationChannel channel = notificationManager.GetNotificationChannel(channelName);
        if (channel == null)
        {
            channel = new NotificationChannel(channelName, channelName, NotificationImportance.Low)
            {
                LockscreenVisibility = NotificationVisibility.Public
            };
            channel.SetShowBadge(true);
            notificationManager.CreateNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
    // build your notification
}
```